# Flutter create a passowrd rules dialog

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dialog, passwords

at the moment i try to revised my password textfield.
I'm adding passwort rules.
For Example the password must allways 8 letters length...
Now i want a dialog for more useful information for the user.
I found in the internet a nice example.

Here the example:

[image]

My problem, i don't know how i can create this dialog in flutter.
I found the alertDialog in internet, but the background changes and the dialog close after the user klick on screen.

Here a emxample from AlertDialog:

[image]

Anyone have a idea how i can create a dialog like the first example.
The dialog should always visible.
Also if the user klick on screen.
But it should also allow the user to edit the textfield.

Many thx (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to toast when the user clicks on submit button you can show this or you can show in text form field error text so user gets specific text like "Enter your name".

Comment: Hello @Dave. Thx for your answer. The toast is a nice idea. I will try it. Many thx (: